# what is the standard way of using behavior-driven development (BDD) for robot framework?

Tags: robotframework

## Guide me how to use when, then, and etc

Sometimes i try to use
*When
And
And
Then*
and sometimes
*Given
When
Then
When
Then*

Is this valid ???

Comment: Well, if it is working - it is a valid option.

I would suggest to use AND inside When and Then conditions and also split scenarios when possible. It would make your test specs clean and transparent to others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really a question related to Robot Framework.
Gherkin Given, When, Then syntax is a small part of BDD.

RF does handle Gherkin prefixes on Keywords and most IDEs (with RF plugins) do also.

As for "sometimes Given When Then When Then"... this is typically not advised in BDD, but technically you can do as you like because the syntax really doesn't DO anything. It can help you make tests more readable and understandable.

I would argue that once you have Then that you should not see anymore Given or Whens, only Ands.

The Then is the assertion/outcome of the behaviour. If you feel you need another When-Then, you most likely need another test.

Answer (score 0):

It is valid. If we use the way you mention in the question, we are mostly abusing the use of BDD. The question is tool agnostic.

**BDD recommends: 1 feature -> 1 Behaviour ->1 Scenario -> 1 TestCase-> 1 result**

You will cover more behaviours in BDD scenario, When you have multiple combinations of When-Then(like in your question). You will have a choice of dividing that scenario into independent scenarios. Just make sure you use the proper Given (preconditions) steps.

You can And as many times as possible in combination with Given or When or Then.The Golden Rule of BDD is to make sure the scenarios we write should be understood by the other readers intuitively. The more keywords you use the more information you are providing to the readers. More the information, more confusion in understanding the system behaviours. We should be cautious on how better we manage the information in one scenario.